# Using php variables inside image url

Tags: php, html

If i have 2 php variables $latitude and $longitude how do i pass them to the url e.g. if latitude is 12 and longitude is 15 the url would be

```
<img border="0" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=12,15&zoom=16"
```

I've tried echoing the url components separately but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

```
$lat = 12;
$long = 15;
$img = "<img border='0' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$lat,$long&zoom=16' />" 
echo $img;
```

You could also do:

```
$img = "<img border='0' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=". $lat. ",". $long."&zoom=16' />"
```

Comment: You need to have single quotes around <img tag

Comment: Or the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you've tried but this would do it

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" . $lat . "," . $long ."&zoom=16";
Echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
<img border="0" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?php echo $latitude; ?>,<?php echo $longitude; ?>&zoom=16"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<img border="0" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?=$latitude?>,<?=$longitude?>&zoom=16"/>
```

`<?=$latitude?>`, just a short echo, is the same as doing `<?php echo $latitude; ?>`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Hiya, this may well answer the question... but don't forget that total n00bs will likely somebody come and find this question/answer and will wonder why this works... can you please give some explanation for why/how your solution works? :)

Comment: okay, it's <?=$latitude?>, just a short echo, is the same as doing <?php echo $latitude ?>

Answer (score 0):

To make it look simpler. Just echo the whole thing.

```
<?php
    $latitude  = 12 ;
    $longitude = 15 ;

    echo "<img border='0' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$latitude,$longitude&zoom=16'>" ;
?>
```